# A verification request upon a combinatorial problem

Tags: probability, proof-verification

An urn contains $100$ balls numbered from $1$ to $100$. Four are removed at random without being replaced. Find the probability that the number on the last ball is smaller than the number on the first
ball.

**MY ATTEMPT**

If the first removed ball is $2$, then there is $1$ possibility for the last ball and $98\cdot 97$ for the other two. Analogously, if the first removed ball is $3$, then there are $2$ possibilities for the last ball and $98\cdot 97$ for the other two. According to this reasoning, there are

\begin{align*}
1\cdot 1\cdot 98\cdot 97 + 1\cdot 2\cdot 98\cdot 97 + \ldots + 1\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot 97 = \left[\frac{(1+99)\cdot99}{2}\right]\cdot98\cdot 97
\end{align*}

possible results which satisfy the given restriction. Consequently, the sought probability is
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(E) = \frac{50\cdot 99\cdot 98\cdot 97}{100\cdot 99\cdot 98 \cdot 97} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Could someone please tell me if I am right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct. There are much easier solutions (a symmetry argument being possibly the best), but yours works.

Comment: Could you please explain it for me? If possible, write it as an answer.

Comment: Either the first is larger than the second, or it is smaller, and re-numbering the balls in the opposite order flips these two probabilities without changing their values, thus their probabilities are equal.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple argument:

Either the number on the last ball is greater than the number on the last ball or less than the first ball's number. Hence the required probability is $\frac12$.